# Is there any vector (x) which is not in subspace B and a vector (y) which is in subspace B, such that (x + y) is in subspace B?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can you have a vector outside the subspace that when added to a vector in the subspace results in a vector inside the subspace?

Comment: No, of course: if $y$ is in $B$, $-y$ is too, and therefore  $(x+y)+(-y)=x$ is in $B$.

Answer (score 0):

No. If $y\in B$ then $-y\in B$. Then given $(x+y)\in B$ and $-y\in B$, then by definition of subspace means $(x+y)+(-y)=x\in B$.

Comment: I thought that maybe the (closed under scalar multiplication property) could reject the vector even tho the (closed under addition property) applies.

Comment: Not when you multiply with integers like $-1$